# Is there a way to create a folder outside application directory in flutter?

Tags: flutter

The function getExternalStorageDirectory() and ApplicationDocumentDirectory() gives the same directory to me that is inside the android folder. I like to create a folder in storage/emulated/0 , i tried explicitly creating it with
Directory('storage/emulated/0').create(); then it says you have no permission. And i gave all the possible permissions and still gets the same result. Is there any way to create a folder in storage/emulated/0 ?

NB: _getPermission returns a bool according to the permission status. This code works well in an emulator but it is not working in an actual device.

```
 takePhoto(BuildContext context) async {
 if ( await _getPermission(Permission.manageExternalStorage)){
   
 final image =await picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
 var newPath = "storage/emulated/0/takephotosaver";
 var directory = Directory(newPath).create();
 File fileIMage = File(image!.path);
 var imageName = DateTime.now().toString();
 fileIMage.copy("$newPath/$imageName.jpg");
 Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>MyPreview(fileIMage)));
 }
```

}
}

Edit :-
This code is working in android version 9 and below but not working in android 10 and 11. Is there a way to display the image taken by my camera in a separate folder?

Answer (score 3):

Things have changed after android 10. You shouldn't create folders in `storage/emulated/0` now. Google is strict about that, and your app may get rejected if you publish your app in Google PlayStore. If you still want to do that then add this permission in your `AndroidManifest.xml`.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

And to get the permission from the user do this,

```
if (await Permission.manageExternalStorage.request().isGranted) {...}
```

**Edit:**

Whenever you create a new file the device can't automatically find it. You'd have to manually tell the device to refresh for the files. Before you'd have to refresh all the files in the device for it to get updated which was very inefficient, but now you could just send the path of the file that you want to get updated. You can use the [media_scanner](https://pub.dev/packages/media_scanner) plugin to do so.

Or If you wanna do it yourself with kotlin then here's the code,

```kotlin
private fun broadcastFileUpdate(path: String){
    context.sendBroadcast(Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE,Uri.fromFile(File(path))))
}
```

Comment: Then where can I create a folder ? Only in android root folder?

Comment: You are allowed to create folders in `applicationFileDirectory` and `externalStorageDirectory`. Although you can store files in the music, documents, downloads directories without any additional permissions.

Comment: Actually that getexternaldirectory is not giving me a directory that is outside if android folder

Comment: `getApplicationFileDirectory` returns something like "/data/data/package_name" which can only be accessed with root permission. `getExternalStorageDirectory` returns something like "/storage/emulated/Android/data/package_name" and can be accessed by any user by going to the android folder. I presume that you think since it's called "external storage" it will return a location outside of android folder, but no, the folder in android directory is the external directory (is not in root directory).

Comment: I requested for manageExternalStorage permission and I added the permission in android manifest but it says "No permissions found in the manifest for :[ ]22". What to do?

Comment: Did you detach the app and again do `flutter run` after modifying the android manifest?

Comment: Yes i did that but the issue now is Iam able to create such a folder but not able fo copy the file to it.

Comment: @VivekTV check the updated answer :)

Comment: Sure. Thank you

Comment: Can i use the gallery saver plugin for that.